# AngularJS use directive-name in scope as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I have nested angular.js templates. Each template has it's own directive. Based of the data passed to the ParentTemplate, angular.js should call the matching directive.

```
<div class="parent-template">
    <div class="{{childTemplate}}"></div>
    <div class="template1"></div>
</div>
```

Lets say that **`$scope.childTemplate = template1`**. Both divs evaluate to the same content **`<div class="template1"></div>`** but only the second div calls the directive to show the template as expected.

I need a dynamic way to call the corresponding template directive

Here is the directive for template1

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('template1', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    templateUrl: 'templates/template1.html'
}
});
```

Directives for other templates directives work similar.

Comment: Based on what is shown both locations are in same scope so you have oversimplified the html example. Need to provide more details about these directives and show proper nesting

Comment: edited my question @charlietfl. If I replace {{childTemplate}} in the div-elem with template1, everything works as exprected. The variable {{childTemplate}} just doesn't get replaced with the proper value

Comment: Where  is the directive code? You mentioned passing data to directive but none is shown. The html still shows both instances of `childTemplate` are in the same scope. There is no way for us to replicate or assess your issue with what is shown

Comment: I updated the question with the directive and hope it is more clear now. let me know if you need further details

Comment: Suggest you create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) demo that replicates your problem. Since you aren't using isolated scope in that directive it will inherit scope of parent and again, both instances shown are in same scope

Comment: I feel like you know it already but assigning a class name to an element doesn't make it a directive. Instead of `<div class="myTemplate"></div>` you should do `<my-template></my-template>`

Answer (score 0):

You try to set the class of the DOM element.
You can do this with ngClass.

Otherwise if you would like to set your directive as an attribute of the DOM element. Like this: `<div template1> </div>`

You can try this way:

```
 var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
    myEl.attr('myattr',"attr val");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div ng-class="childTemplate"><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever solve this? I have a similar challenge, which I currently solve by using ng-include, like so:

```
<div class="parent-template">
    <div ng-include="'templates/template1'"></div>
    <div class="template1"></div>
</div>
```

This works for your example, but gets more tricky when a directive does more than just wrapping a template, e.g. working with the DOM or adding a controller.

What you can do in that case is using the directive inside the template.

However, this feels all kinda hacky, i'd like a more direct approach

This was, for me, all sparked by an article on react plugins, in which you basically enumerate over a set of react component to get a feature set: https://nylas.com/blog/react-plugins